# How can I add text to the end of each line of a File in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file called Names.txt; inside this is a list of names of people, separated by a line.
e.g;

```
Joe
Alex
Patricia
Emma
```

How, in node.js, would I edit the file so there is an ":lastname" added to each line?

Comment: Hi, Can you show an example of what you've tried so far and someone might be able to point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: It's fixed @Errsen. No need to thumbs down it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd get the file, split into lines, modify those lines, and write the file back again

```
fs.readFile('/path/to/Names.txt', function(err, result) {

    if (err) // handle errors

    var lines = result.split(/(\n|\r\n)/);

    var new_content = lines.map(function(line) {
        return line + ' lastname';
    }).join("\r\n")

    fs.writeFile('/path/to/Names.txt', new_content, 'utf8', function(err) {
        if (err) // handle errors
        console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });
});
```

That's the jist of it. Of course, you could keep a map of firstnames and lastnames, and insert the appropriate lastname, or do all sorts of other things, but you'd still have to go through the same process, fetch, split on newlines, modify, join together and save.

Comment: Disregard my comment; I added 'utf8' so I get the correct encoding, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the previous answer, you would be looking to add the UTF8 encoding by implementing it as a parameter after the file path, it would look like this...

```
fs.readFile('/path/Names.txt', 'utf8', function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var lines = res.split(/\n/);
  var new_content = lines.map(function(line) {
    return line + ' lastname';
  }).join('\n');

  fs.writeFile('/path/Names.txt', new_content, 'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
  });
});
```

this should fix your issue with the buffer looking return from the read command.

Comment: Thanks, but why does, when i load the file in notepad, it shows all the text clustered together. Is there anything I can do to fix this because it's messing up my other script which gets it line by line.

Comment: This is likely because notepad does not know how to interpret a line break command in the unix way
which is `\n`
In a windows program, you need to use 
`\r\n`
for a full carriage return

Comment: Thanks, \r\n worked. I didn't see it because you edited it